# How to delete by int entered? (Value of a variable inside an object inside an ArrayList)

Tags: java, algorithm

I want to delete by the ID the user enters as the Long id parameter being the ID the user enters.

```
public Address deleteAddress(Long id) {
        int idInt = id.intValue();
        ArrayList<Address> addresses = new ArrayList<Address>();
        addressRepository.findAll().forEach(addresses::add);
        if (addresses.size() <= id || id < 0) {
            throw new ArithmeticException("ID entered out of possible range");
        }
        addressRepository.delete(addresses.get(idInt));
        return null;
    }
```

The problem is when I use address.get(idInt) it takes me to the position in the array of [0]. I want to go to the position in the array where ID equals the value 1 in the variable Long ID inside the object inside the array. for example: [image]

The id has the value of Long 1 inside [0]. Is there a way to check if the value of id inside the object equals the id entered and then delete that position in the array?

The reason why this is a problem is because next time the program runs, the ArrayList will be one length shorter, so next time I enter to delete the value of say 2, it will delete position [2] in the array which will now hold the ID of 3 because the array list would have shrunk by 1 position. Any ideas?

Comment: Working. Thanks, I feel dumb.

Comment: Happy to help. I've made that an answer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `findById` to get the row you want and call `delete` on that. There's no need to load all the rows.